# When do shops change inventory?

Tags: borderlands-2

Do I have to wait a certain amount of time before the shops get new stock or is it something as simple as changing zones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shops change inventory every 20 minutes.  There is a convenient countdown timer under the item of the day.

The only exception is if someone currently has the shop open, the items won't switch until everyone is out of the shop interface.

Comment: I was under the impression the timer only applied to the Item of the Day

Comment: Nope, all items in the shop change when it hits zero.  I've held it open so a co-op partner could buy a regular item in the list, and after I dropped the menu, all the items refreshed.  As these things go, the new item of the day was significantly better than the gun he just bought :)

Comment: There is a relic which speeds up the shop cycle time, the _Lucrative Opportunity_. I got mine as a side-quest reward from Marcus.